Efficiently (no copy) access a property of objects in a list via another list pointing to that single property?
Is there a way to provide efficient access to a property (of reference type) in instances of a class in a list via another list that references that single property? My idea would thus be to not have a copy of that property be made but access via the second list directly the original property.
internal class MyClass
{
    public string prop1;
    public string prop2;
}

List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();

List<string> prop1List = new List<string>();

My intent is to have prop1List allow access to property prop1 for all instances in myList.
Doing the following is to me the immediate solution but I don't like IEnumerables for their less efficiency and limitations in accessing data.
IEnumerable<string> prop1List = myList.Select(x => x.prop1);

On the other hand doing the following creates a copy of data
List<string> prop1List = myList.Select(x => x.prop1).ToList();


Please provide some example code of what you are trying to do.

Your question is hard to understand. In the first place, why would there be a copy of property or an object when you are referring them through the lists?

Does it need to be a list? You could just do prop1List = myList.Select(m => m.prop1)

First of all those are fields, not properties. Second efficient access doesn't explain anything. What is the inefficiency you want to fix? Is it real or imagined? Strings are reference types, so no copy is made

Only worried about finding deficiencies in questions instead of focusing on the intent, that is more often than not very clear. This place is always crawling with Taliban only worried about rules and finding violations other that helping each other.

String is immutable, so cannot be changed, only replaced. But you could add another level of indirection:
public class Ref<T>{
   public T Value {get;set;}
   public Ref(T value) => Value = value;
}
internal class MyClass
{
    public Ref<string> prop1 {get;} = new Ref<string>(null)
    public string prop2;
}

List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();

List<Ref<string>> prop1List = new List<Ref<string>>();

This way changes to the prop1 will be reflected in the prop1List. This can be useful in some cases, but I'm not sure it will be a good pattern for your particular use case.
A possibly better option would be to use a projection:
IEnumerable<string> prop1List = myList.Select(i => i.prop1);

This way there is less risk that the lists get out of sync. The downsides is that there is no efficient indexing or length property on IEnumerable. But if that is needed you could create your own projection class that implements IReadOnlyList<T>.
It will also somewhat depend on what you mean by "efficient". UI-related lists of strings tend to be fairly short, say thousands of strings. And for short lists performance is usually not that important, since the absolute time is still so low.

What you have suggested is exactly my current solution, but I don't like it. IEnumerables don't support indices and require an iterator which provides less efficient access to data.

@whatever as I suggested, you can make your own class that works the same as .select, except that it produces a IReadOnlyList, with support for indexing and count. It should not be very difficult. Count is trivial and the indexer is just selector(backingList[i]);.

I don't see how what you are suggesting could be any better or any more efficient than doing a var prop1List = myList.Select(x => x.prop1).ToList();.

@whatever The crucial difference is if the list ever changes. If the list is small, non-changing, and you need to iterate it fully, then yes, doing as you propose is simpler and easier. But with an projection class that wraps the original, any changes in the original will automatically be reflected in the projection.
